# Can't get :visible to work with index()

Tags: jquery, indexing, visible

This is my graphic design portfolio site and I'm having a bit of trouble with my filter. I've created it using jQuery and classes. When one clicks on a link it hides all the '.tags' that aren't it. All of this works correctly. (Lines 5-19)

Starting on line 21, I've created a function that dynamically adds a div and content below the item. It finds how many elements exist, the position of the current element, and finds the position the new div should be inserted (at the end of the 3 column row). All of this works correctly on its own.

**The problem is that when some '.tags' are filtered, the second function doesn't correctly find the position of the current element.** It's because I'm not actually removing the elements from the source code, simply hiding them - I want to keep it that way so I don't need to keep reloading the content.

```
var portfolio = '#portfolio > a';
var elements = $(portfolio).children(':visible').length; //finds how many elements are in the portfolio
var getPosition = $(portfolio).siblings('a :visible').addBack().index(this);  //find the position of the div
```

The above code is the problem area (lines 25-26), but here's the entire code for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/cQUMs/5/

My variable *elements* has no trouble getting the correct number of elements whether the filter is used or not. ***getPosition* gets the right position before anything is filtered, but retains that number; I need it to update dynamically.**

Comment: Instead of click method you can try with "on" method so that it may work (for ex : $(document).on("click", "nav a", function(){ // content goes here .....}))

Comment: @Mahipal is using `on("click"` better practice than using `click()`? I tried replacing it but it didn't do anything different. `$(portfolio).on("click", function...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `this` you're indexing against is an `a` element. So try this ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/cQUMs/6/)):

```
//find the position of the div
var getPosition = $(portfolio).children(':visible').index( $(this).children() );
```

Comment: Thanks @Mottie! I'm getting the right values now, but uncovered a problem in my insert math. It's inserting the dynamic div and ignoring the visibility. So it's putting it in the right position according to the HTML, but visually or as the user sees it, it's in the wrong spot.

Comment: working on a variable that offsets the insert position according to the visibility. It's sending the div to the end, mostly, which kind of works... looks like: `var offsetVisibility = $(portfolio).children().length - elements;` `var insert = offsetVisibility + (getPosition + (totalColumns - (getPosition % totalColumns) - 1));`

Comment: Try using `.children('.tags:visible')` to target the specific divs and not the dynamically added one

Comment: Also, in case you might be interested, [jQuery Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) plugin does pretty much the same thing with nice transition animation :)

Comment: ha! Of course I hear about a plugin after spending a bunch of time on it. Thanks for your help!